# continuous operation inkstrorkecontainer.clear() and addstrokes() caue EXCEPTION in UWP

Tags: c, uwp, uwp-xaml

the Sink1 is a inkstrokecontainer, it does not binding to an inkcanvas(I also tried binding it to an inkcanvas to avoid EXCEPTION, but still useless). 
ink1 is an inkcanvas on xaml.

```
 public sealed partial class wpage : Page


         {
            public wpage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();

                ink1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer = inkStrokeContainer1;
                ink1.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected += InkPresenter_StrokesCollected;
                ink1.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
             }

                public  void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)

            {sink1.Clear();
             sink1.AddStrokes(args.Strokes);
            }


    }

above code will cause an


    #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
                UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

I also have tried:

```
public async void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)

   {     await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, new DispatchedHandler(() =>
         {    {sink1.Clear();
             sink1.AddStrokes(args.Strokes);
            });

     }
```

but still is useless  also bomb with

```
 #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); .
```

I also tried to run them bothe in  taks.run and Dispatcher.RunAsync, also bomb.
I do this because I need to serialize the inkstroke in isf format with the save method in the inkstrokecontainer class, serialize with other method the result size is too big.

Comment: This is not C at all. Please fix the tags. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the Sink1 is a inkstrokecontainer, it does not binding to an inkcanvas

This is the cause of the problem.

`sink1` and `ink1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer` are not the same `InkStrokeContainer`, which means that `Stroke` in `InkCanvas` cannot be directly added to another `StrokeContainer`.

You can try to modify your code:

```cs
private void InkPresenter_Collect(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)
{
    sink1.Clear();
    foreach (var item in args.Strokes)
    {
        sink1.AddStroke(item.Clone());
    }
}
```

In simple terms, the `Stroke` already displayed on the screen belongs to `ink1`, you can't add it to another `InkStrokeContainer`, but you can get its clone object, the cloned object does not belong to `ink1`, you can add it.

Best regards.

Comment: thanks, I forgot this. I stop the work about inkstroke for one year and forgot the important point.

Comment: sorry to disturb you, Do you have used azure b2c or oauth2? Can you teach me How the webservice/webapi to verificate whether a token(such as a token provided by a native client) is from the azure b2c instead of a fake one? Does my webserver will Resolve the token by the Client secret from the b2c thus  can verificate  the token?Dose the b2c will  transfer a token copy to the protected service/webapi ? or the b2c only give the token to the  mobile client? thank you.

Comment: Hi, your question seems to be irrelevant to the content of the current question. If you have questions about `Azure`, please open a new thread to describe your problem, our community partners will answer it.